# SAP UI5 how to set the colour state for the Process Flow Lane Header

Tags: sapui5

Im facing an issue in Process Flow. Im trying to set the state of the ProcessFlowLaneHeader to Positive, But I'm not able to see the node in green colour. Can you please help me how can i fix this issue. 
Below is the code that i have tried..

```
<ui:ProcessFlow class="processFlow" scrollable="false" showLabels="false">                      
    <ui:lanes>
        <ui:ProcessFlowLaneHeader iconSrc="sap-icon://order-status" text="Apply" press="onNodeLeaveApply"
                            state="{[sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowNodeState.Positive]}" position="0"/>
        <ui:ProcessFlowLaneHeader state="{[sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowNodeState.Positive]}" iconSrc="sap-icon://customer" text="Review"
                            press="onNodeLeaveReview" position="1"/>
        <ui:ProcessFlowLaneHeader state="{[sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowNodeState.Positive]}" iconSrc="sap-icon://inventory" text="Sent"
                            press="onNodeLeaveSent" position="2"/>
    </ui:lanes>
</ui:ProcessFlow>
```

Please check the screenshot here I'm not able to get the nodes in Green colour..

[image]

When I tried to change the node from Controller by pressing the node, it is changing to grey(Neutral). Below is my Controller Code.

```
     onNodeLeaveApply:function(oEvent){

 oEvent.mParameters.oParent.mAggregations.lanes[0].setState(["sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowNodeState.Positive"]);
            },
```

[image]

Please help me how can I change the state to Green Colour(Positive)

Thank you in advance

Comment: What you're referencing to is not the node, but the LaneHeader. The nodes are the square notes below these headers

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the first answer was hasty and incorrect. The state property is indeed an array of pairs { state, value }. 
The event handler of "press" can access the ProcessFlowLaneHeader as the source of the event, so oEvent.mParameters.oParent.mAggregations.lanes[0] line should be changed to oEvent.getSource():

```
onNodeLeaveApply: function(oEvent) {
    oEvent.getSource().setState([{
        state: sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowNodeState.Positive,
        value: 20
    },
    {
        state: sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowNodeState.Negative,
        value: 10
    }]);
}
```

Instead of sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowNodeState.Negative or sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowNodeState.Positive you can use strings "Negative" and "Positive" with the same result:

```
onNodeLeaveApply: function(oEvent) {
    oEvent.getSource().setState([{
                state: "Positive",
                value: 20
            },
            {
                state: "Negative",
                value: 10
            }]);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But it didnt worked for me..:( Im not understanding what is the issue exactly..

Comment: Awesome.. This Solution worked for me. Thank you for your observation, You helped me with your quick solution.. Kudos.. :)