# Set State of ProcessFlowLaneHeader in Formatter

Tags: sapui5

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706746/sap-ui5-how-to-set-the-colour-state-for-the-process-flow-lane-header), but I need to do this via formatter function.

I need to set each LaneHeader to a state given the `ProcessFlow` control has no nodes or documents, but it is not setting successfully!

**View**: Here in the `state` property I'm able to access the control instance through adding `namespace.controller.controllerName.prototype` to the regular `.formatter.fnFormatterFunction`

```html
<ProcessFlow id="workflowMain" lanes="{workflowMain>/}">
  <lanes>
    <ProcessFlowLaneHeader iconSrc="sap-icon://order-status" laneId="{workflowMain>/Level}" press="onHeaderPress" text="{workflowMain>Level}" 
      state="{path:'workflowMain>Status',formatter:'the.SandboxOfTheGods.controller.Two_processFlowAndTreeTable.prototype.formatter.WorkflowLaneStatus'}"
      position="{workflowMain>SequenceID}" />
  </lanes>
</ProcessFlow>
```

**Formatter**

```js
sap.ui.define([], function() {
  "use strict";
  return {
    WorkflowLaneStatus: function(sStatus) {
      if (sStatus === "APPROVED") {
        this.setState({
          state: "Positive",
          value: 100
        });
      } else if (sStatus === "PENDING") {
        this.setState({
          state: "Negative",
          value: 100
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

**Controller**

```js
onBeforeRendering: function() {
  var that = this;
  sScorecardNumber = "6000000683";

  var aFilters = [
    new Filter("Scorecardnum", FilterOperator.EQ, sScorecardNumber)
  ];
  this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("workflowMain").read("/MainWorkflowSet", {
    filters: aFilters,
    success: function(oData) {
      var iResultsLength = oData.results.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < iResultsLength; i++) {
        oData.results[i].SequenceID = i; //change 1st entry's SequenceID to 0 instead of 1 & every entry afterward to be incremental from 0
      }
      that.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(oData.results), "workflowMain");
    },
    error: function(oError) {
      MessageToast.show("Error");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of debacle, how I solved this was to return a value in the fnFormatterFunction rather than deliberately trying to set the value via a setter method in fnFormatterFunction:

```js
var sState;
if (sStatus === "APPROVED") sState = "Positive";
else if (sStatus === "PENDING") sState = "Negative";
return [{
  state: sState,
  value: 100
}];
```

*Note: returned value MUST be contained in an array as the property expects an array object, not merely an object itself.

Instead of setting it:

```js
if (sStatus === "APPROVED") {
  this.setState([{
    state: "Positive",
    value: 100
  }]);
} else if (sStatus === "PENDING") {
  this.setState([{
    state: "Negative",
    value: 100
  }]);
}
```

Comment: Now try doing it without if/else for more clean and maintainable code.

Comment: @Marc switch stmts?

Comment: Nope. Switch is just a different syntax for the same idea. See the following snippet for a better solution https://gist.github.com/OTTOxMarc/2a329147249e96bf6b50721f1b5120aa

Comment: interesting, ive never seen such a thing before. maintainability shoots through the roof on this one. how does it compare performance-wise? is this called 'mapping'?

Comment: Mapping usually means to apply a function to every element in an array. I guess this construct here is a simple dictionary (which is called map in other languages) which can often remove switches/if else

Comment: really good to know, and i assume this way consumes less compute, but more memory. thanks marc :pray: